# How to write SQL date format Like query into LINQ Or Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity frame work, i want to convert SQL query of LIKE date  to Entity framework.
here is the query

```
 Select * from Schedule where SerialNo='11119' and DueDate like '%2012%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
dbcontext.Schedules.Where(s => s.SerialNo == '11119' && s.DueDate.Year == 2012)
```

Comment: What type is DueDate? You should edit your post and show us how looks like your Schedule entity.

Comment: it's sir Datetime in SQL database & here is function...................                              public List<Schedule> GetListBySearch(string search)
        {
           return db.Schedule.Where(s => s.SerialNo == '11119' && s.DueDate == '2012').ToList();
        }

Comment: Add the Schedule class to your question, we will have a better idea

Comment: Actually sir, Schedule is the table name as db.schedule & I want to get a list of history for serialno=11119 where Duedate=2012

Comment: If Schedule is the table name and not a class, then in List<Schedule> what is Schedule?

Comment: sir, As class, I use Schedule table's fields like get and set properties of class, mean no need to make a separate class & then define its attributes... i use list of Schedule like List<Schedule>

Comment: Ok, DueDate is nullable!